# Worst Case Response Time (WCRT) analysis the only necessary test for real time tasks?

Tags: logic, operating-systems, scheduling, real-time

Recently, I have taken a Computer Science exam for the course *Operating Systems*. One question was as follows:

> Which statements about real-time operating systems are true?

I selected two options, but according to the exam answers, three options were correct for this question. The following option is also correct (quote):

> A Worst Case Reponse Time Analysis should **always** be performed to check whether tasks can be executed within set deadlines, unless the utilisation calculation is smaller than the utilisation bound.

My first thought was that this answer option could not be true due to its strong wording. It states that the **Worst Case Response Time (WCRT) Analysis** is always necessary (and the only necessary and sufficient test), except when the utilisation test is sufficient. Is it not true that there can be more tests, that are sufficient and/or necessary, which have not been mentioned as part of this answer option?

For instance, the following article suggests a new test for real time tasks which is not mentioned in the answer option: [Determining rate monotonic schedulability of real-time periodic tasks using continued fractions](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2022.106296)

Do you think it is therefore defensible that the aforementioned answer option is false (instead of true)?